# how to write a firebase Realtime database rule to match root folder child folders name with New Data custom uid

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

i want go give some user Special permission to write to a folder like (Sp_Adim) if they have a custom UID . to give permission all custom UID saved in a folder in real time data base how can i check this

```
    "Newdata.child('S_uid').val === root.child(\"$folder\")"
```

i tried its not working even the folder are inside there  Cust_uid/sdsd  get denied

```
    root.child('Cust_uid').child(\"$custom_id\").exists() === 'sdsd'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quick answer below. If you have more questions, I recommend posting a new question after reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as we may need more context to understand what's going wrong beyond the three things I point out below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're putting the wildcard capture variables in quotes, which is not correct.

If you have a `$custom_id` variable  in your rules tree, you can use that in a specific rule with:

```
root.child('Cust_uid').child(custom_id).exists()
```

If you want to check the value of a node under that root, be sure to call `.val` to the end of path too. So:

```
newdata.child('S_uid').val === root.child($folder).val()
```

Finally, note that case is important, so it's `newData` and not `NewData`.

Comment: root.child($folder).val() i use this gives me a  syntax error so i change to root.child('$folder').val() now i am able to publish . then i want to check the incoming data with root data  "newData.child('id').val() === root.child('admin').child('$anyfoldername').val()" why i am getting  denied is this not allowed i just need to check the any folderName that in adminfolder match the incoming newData id

Comment: `'$folder'` will not work, as it just makes that a string value rather than a variable. If you have an error on that, it most likely means that you didn't define a `$folder` [wildcard variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#wildcard_capture_variables) above it in your rules. It's hard to say more without enough context, so if this problem persists I recommend updating your question to include a more [complete repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or to post a new question with such a repro.